# RegionPlot3D and Texture

Tags: textures, plotting

I'm getting a white solid instead of a solid with texture, I'm not sure what is wrong:

```
RegionPlot3D[M, {a, -3, 3}, {c, -3, 3}, {d, -3, 3}, PlotPoints -> 100,
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Texture[ExampleData[{"Texture", "Bricks2"}]]]
```

Here M is the solid defined by:

```
M:= (a < 0 && ((c < 0 && (d < 0 || d > -2 a - c)) || (c > 
        0 && (d < -c || d > -2 a)))) || (a > 
    0 && ((c < 0 && (d < -2 a || d > -c)) || (c > 
        0 && (d < -2 a - c || d > 0))))
```

Comment: Adding `TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#1, #2, #3} &),
Lighting -> "Neutral",
Mesh -> False` works pretty well. I'm holding off on writing an answer though, hoping that someone can explain how texture coordinates work. The rule of thumb seems to be that `{x,y,z}` i.e. cartesian coordinates work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
M := (a <  0 && ((c < 0 && (d < 0 || d > -2 a - c)) || (c >  0 && (d < -c || d > -2 a)))) || (a > 0 && ((c < 0 && (d < -2 a || d > -c)) || (c >  0 && (d < -2 a - c || d > 0))))

RegionPlot3D[M, {a, -3, 3}, {c, -3, 3}, {d, -3, 3}, 
 Lighting -> "Neutral", Mesh -> False, PlotPoints -> 10, 
 PlotStyle :> Texture[ExampleData[{"ColorTexture", "WhiteMarble"}]], 
 TextureCoordinateScaling -> True]
```

[image]

```
RegionPlot3D[M, {a, -3, 3}, {c, -3, 3}, {d, -3, 3}, 
 Lighting -> "Neutral", Mesh -> False, PlotPoints -> 10, 
 PlotStyle :> Texture[ExampleData[{"Texture", "Bricks2"}]], 
 TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#1, #2} &)]
```

[image]

**EDIT**

Sergio's ansatz didn't work because one has to add:

```
Lighting -> "Neutral"
Mesh -> False
```

Also, it is necessary to remove `Directive`.

Comment: Thanks again! In the second example, why the bricks are in black and white? Is it because Texture instead of ColorTexture does not add any color or is some other option?

Comment: @SergioParreiras - it's because the bricks are supplied only in b&w. In this case you have to use "Texture". With marble it's just the other way around. One has to experiment a little bit here.